# WooCommerce Billing Checkout Field Add custom Field Where product name dynamically Fill

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

In Billing Add a custom Checkout field where the product name dynamically fill so in user it's link with product in all users. or there is other way to do it

I Need Code in php or Anything Thats help me.

Comment: Checkout the below suggested answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
/**
 * Custom field for checkout page
 */
function kb_custom_checkout_field() {
    $product_names = array();
    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
        $product = $cart_item['data'];
        if ( ! empty( $product ) ) {
            $p_name = $product->get_name();
            array_push( $product_names, $p_name );
        }
    }
    $product_names = implode( ',', $product_names );
    echo '<p class="custom_field_checkout"><label for="appform"> Product: </label>' . $product_names . '</p>';
    
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_before_order_review', 'kb_custom_checkout_field' );
```

I have shown the product name in the `<p>` tag.
It will be shown like:
[image]